# Why does gradle think my 'libraries' directory is a project

Tags: android, configuration, gradle, dependencies

I was trying to run some gradle commands that included specifying a configuration, but was getting errors stating "Configuration with name 'every name I tried' not found." This is usually caused by a missing build.gradle file in one of the dependencies. Sure enough I found the offending project:

```
Evaluating project ':libraries' using empty build file.
```

But libraries is not actually a project, it is just the folder that holds all the project dependencies. The libraries directory is on the same level as my main project, and my settings.gradle file is:

```
include ':libraries:some-sdk'
include ':libraries:another-sdk'
```

And my dependencies in my build.gradle are:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:some-sdk')
    compile project(':libraries:another-sdk')
    compile files('libs/some-library.jar')
    compile 'some-maven-repo:some-artifact:X.X.X'
}
```

I have also reproduced the issue using commonsware's multiproject demo: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/HelloMultiProject

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is due to the syntax you are using. Gradle is interpreting `:libraries` as a project, which is parent to your 'sdk' projects. If you want those two projects to effectively fall directly under the root project, yet still exist in a child directory you can explicitly specify the `projectDir`.

Change your settings.gradle to look like:

```
def String[] modules = ['some-sdk', 'another-sdk']

include modules

modules.each { name ->
    def p = findProject(":${name}")
    p.projectDir = new File("libraries/${name}")
}
```